# Combine two MySQL queries with calculation

Tags: mysql

I have got two tables with different information but want to combine them into the report as one table.

I could manage to combine tables with this queries:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `info`, `food`, `drinks`, `service`, `ambience`, `hygiene`, `recommend`, `best_menu`, `best_service`, `author`, `username` 
FROM `restaurants` RIGHT JOIN `rating` ON `rating`.`rid` IN (1,2,3);
```

But want to calculate all ratings and show in a compact view with name and info like this one:

```
SELECT `rid` as `id`, COUNT(*) as `count`, AVG(`food`+`drinks`+`service`+`ambience`+`hygiene`) as `average`, SUM(`food`) as `food`, SUM(`drinks`) as `drinks`, SUM(`service`) as `service`, SUM(`ambience`) as `ambience`, SUM(`hygiene`) as `hygiene`, concat(round(( SUM(`recommend`)/COUNT(*) * 100 ),2),'%') as `recommended`, `best_menu` as `best`, `best_service` as `service`, `voted` as `last vote` 
FROM `rating` WHERE `rid` IN (3,1,2) GROUP BY `rid` ORDER BY `best_menu`, `best_service`;
```

So my goal is to bring "name" and "info" columns from the first table to the second one.

Please see the example here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5589/35

Highly appreciate your help!

Comment: This is a flawed design. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet!

Comment: So it won't be possible to bring the name by the id?

Comment: All things are possible. Not all things are sensible. The sensible thing is to first fix the design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around I could finally build the correct request.

```
SELECT `rid` as `id`, `name`, `info`, COUNT(*) as `count`, AVG(`food`+`drinks`+`service`+`ambience`+`hygiene`) as `average`, SUM(`food`) as `food`, SUM(`drinks`) as `drinks`, SUM(`service`) as `service`, SUM(`ambience`) as `ambience`, SUM(`hygiene`) as `hygiene`, concat(round(( SUM(`recommend`)/COUNT(*) * 100 ),2),'%') as `recommended`, `best_menu` as `best`, `best_service` as `service`, `voted` as `last vote` 
FROM `rating` JOIN `restaurants` ON `restaurants`.`id` = `rating`.`rid` WHERE `restaurants`.`id` IN (1,2,4) GROUP BY `rid` ORDER BY `best_menu`, `best_service`;
```

In this case I must have ratings for all restaurants otherwise they won't be displayed. I agree with @Strawberry to build a normalised design could help to avoid this issue.

Comment: I would put it more emphatically

Answer (score 1):

While not pretending to be a definitive solution, a normalised design for this schema might be as follows:

```
ratings_index
(rating_id*,rating_title,rating_type(integer,string));

users
(user_id*,username,email)

venues
(venue_id,name,address)

user_integer_ratings
(user_id*,venue_id*,rating_id*,rating)

user_string_ratings
(user_id*,venue_id*,rating_id*,rating)

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @Strawberry